# JMeter how to NOT fail 500 Internal Server Errors

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I am using JMeter as a unit test tool, in parameterised calls where I expect some of the responses to be 500 internal server errors.  I am using BeanShell Assertions to check the responses.

I want some of the 500 internal server errors to NOT be marked as failures if the response contains a specified text.  All 500 server errors are marked as failures.  Is it possible to change the behavior?

Below is an extract from the BeanShell Assertion.

```
if (ResponseCode.equals("500")) {
    Failure = false;
    String respData = new String(ResponseData);

    if (! respData.contains("specific Text")) {
        Failure = true;
        FailureMessage = "500 Internal Server Error:  Unexpected Response.   " + 
            "Response Message: " + respData;
    }
}
```

Thank you and Regards

Answer (score 40, accepted):

UPD: please find most simple & "native" solution below:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9931570/460802

---

In case if you want to do some tricky things in code use the following approach.

Access and modify [SampleResult](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) to change the status from "FAIL" to "PASS" if the code is 500 from your [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) or use [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) instead - they all have access to SampleResult Object.

**1. JSR223 Assertion**

```
if (ResponseCode.equals("500") == true) { 
    SampleResult.setResponseOK();  

    /* the same is 
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
    SampleResult.setResponseCodeOK();
    SampleResult.setResponseMessageOK();
    */
}
```

**2. JSR223 PostProcessor**
Use `prev` instead - to access SampleResult object of the sampler to which one post-processor is attached:

```
if (prev.getResponseCode().equals("500") == true) { 
    prev.setResponseOK();  

    /* the same is 
    prev.setSuccessful(true);
    prev.setResponseCodeOK();
    prev.setResponseMessageOK();
    */
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Adding SampleResult.setResponseOK(); worked perfectly for what I needed.

Comment: @Gazen Ganados, it would be very kindly to accept answer in this case.

Comment: This changes the response code. your other answer is a much better solution imo

Answer (score 58):

Another possible solution is to use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) with checked "Ignore Status" flag added to your sampler:

> **Ignore status**
>   Instructs JMeter to set the status to success initially.
>
> The overall success of the sample is determined by combining the
>   result of the assertion with the existing Response status. When the
>   Ignore Status checkbox is selected, the Response status is forced to
>   successful before evaluating the Assertion.
>
> HTTP Responses with statuses in the 4xx and 5xx ranges are normally regarded as
>   unsuccessful. **The "Ignore status" checkbox can be used to set the
>   status successful before performing further checks.** Note that this
>   will have the effect of clearing any previous assertion failures, so
>   make sure that this is only set on the first assertion.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  I don't want to change the response to OK as suggested in your other answer... I want to assert that the response is the correct error (in my case, 404 Not Found).  So, thanks!

Comment: This is the perfect answer. Saved my time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add a "Response Assertion" after the request you want to pass and the check the "Ignore Status" check box.

Answer (score -2):

Using a BeanShell assertion, force the HTTP Sampler to pass and then pass/fail on a regular Beanshell assertion statement instead:

```
if (ResponseCode.equals("500") == true) { 
    SampleResult.setResponseOK();  

    /* the same is 
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
    SampleResult.setResponseCodeOK();
    SampleResult.setResponseMessageOK();
    */
}
String path = SampleResult.getURL().getPath();
if (!path.contains("anerror")) {
    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "URL Path: didn't contain \"anerror\"" +
        System.getProperty("line.separator") + "URL Path detected: " + path;
}
```