# Jmeter Response Assertion vs. using a Beanshell Post

Tags: jmeter

Looking at the discussion [jmeter-how-to-not-fail-500-internal-server-errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785777/jmeter-how-to-not-fail-500-internal-server-errors), I'd like to know  when should I use a Response Assertion vs. when to use a Beanshell PostProcessor for validating my negative test: is there a Best Practice?

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is: avoid scripting where possible. If you can use Response Assertion to accomplish your scenario - go for it.

A couple of best practices references:

- [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Comment: Thank you. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I just support what Dmitri T posted, but have some additional info, since you asked for any insight.

Best practice is to use the jmeter built in assertion when one exists. There are a few good reasons to go with built in functions.

- Why re-invent the wheel? Why do that work?
- Its going to help you learn what built in tools are available.
- It may to make it easier for others who know jmeter to read your tests

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks.